# libjsc.so not found in react-native - version 0.41

Tags: android, react-native

I am using react native 0.41 and my app crashes with the exception provided below. I unzipped the react native aar but did not found `libjsc.so` under jni/ folder. How can I provide the `libjsc.so`?

```
12-22 17:31:44.103 2273-2273/com.example.sampleapp.photos E/art: dlopen("/data/app/com.example.sampleapp.photos-1/lib/x86/libreactnativejni.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: library "libjsc.so" not found
12-22 17:31:44.181 2009-2657/com.google.android.gms E/MDM: [171] wvj.run: Couldn't connect to Google API client: ksj{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
12-22 17:31:44.214 2273-2273/com.example.sampleapp.photos E/AndroidRuntime:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sampleapp.photos, PID: 2273
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libjsc.so" not found
        at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:331)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:981)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader$1.load(SoLoader.java:279)
        at com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource.loadLibraryFrom(DirectorySoSource.java:69)
        at com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource.loadLibrary(DirectorySoSource.java:40)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:427)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:367)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:332)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactBridge.staticInit(ReactBridge.java:24)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactBridge.<clinit>(ReactBridge.java:20)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactBridge.staticInit(ReactBridge.java:24)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeMap.<clinit>(NativeMap.java:22)
        at com.facebook.react.JSCConfig$1.getConfigMap(JSCConfig.java:14)
        at com.facebook.react.XReactInstanceManagerImpl.recreateReactContextInBackgroundFromBundleLoader(XReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:431)
        at com.facebook.react.XReactInstanceManagerImpl.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner(XReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:426)
        at com.facebook.react.XReactInstanceManagerImpl.createReactContextInBackground(XReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:370)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactRootView.startReactApplication(ReactRootView.java:215)
        at com.example.reactnative.ReactActivity.runReactComponent(ReactActivity.java:107)
        at com.example.reactnative.ReactActivity.createReactComponentView(ReactActivity.java:120)
        at com.example.reactnative.ReactActivity.onCreate(ReactActivity.java:49)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these things

locating the gradle.properties file in the root project, and add

`Android.useDeprecatedNdk=true`

and in build.gradle add this

```
android {  
    ...  
    defaultConfig {  
        ...  
        ndk {  
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"  
        } 
    }
}
```